# How to write in xml file and save it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write in an xml file.

```
await File(path).writeAsString(
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n');
```

The file is created but nothing is written in it. How do I write in xml file?

Answer (score -1):

You can try use [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package with amount of useful features for working with XML. With this package you can easily create XML documents.

For writing a data to a file, try add `mode: FileMode.append` and `flush: true` to `writeAsString` method arguments:

```dart
await File.writeAsString(
    data,
    mode: FileMode.append,
    flush: true,
);
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't figure out from the documentation how to write in file and save it.

Comment: I am added some addition to the answer.